# Failed to retrieve data for empty member item type

Tags: asp.net, azure, umbraco, member, umbraco7

I have just one member type with many properties and I upgraded from Umbraco 6.2.1 to 7.1.6.

When I right click and go to create a new Member of "Dealer Login User" I receive this error:

```
Server error: Contact administrator, see log for full details.
Failed to retrieve data for empty member item type DealerLoginUser
```

When I go to click any of the existing members I receive this error:

```
Server error: Contact administrator, see log for full details.
Failed to retrieve data for member id ac15863825084e1cb1e9e620b3a1a872
```

I dug into the logs on Azure and it's giving me a 500 error and this is what I found:

```
Buffer=")]}',
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The given key was not present in the dictionary.","ExceptionType":"System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException","StackTrace":"   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors.MultiNodeTreePickerPropertyEditor.MultiNodePickerPreValueEditor.ConvertDbToEditor(IDictionary`2 defaultPreVals, PreValueCollection persistedPreVals)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Models.Mapping.ContentPropertyDisplayConverter.ConvertCore(Property originalProp)\r\n   at AutoMapper.TypeConverter`2.Convert(ResolutionContext context)\r\n   at AutoMapper.MappingExpression`2.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ConvertUsing>b__14(ResolutionContext context)\r\n   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.CustomMapperStrategy.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)\r\n   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapMapper.Map(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper)\r\n   at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)"}"
```

I see that it has an error with the "MultiNodeTreePicker" which is also referenced here: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/54018-Upgrading-621-to-714-Failed-to-retrieve-data-for-data-type-error-for-MNTP

That post has a SQL script that I can run:

```
    -- This script should be run after Umbraco install script

USE DatabaseName-- specify database
GO

DECLARE @datatypeIds TABLE (id int);

INSERT INTO @datatypeIds
SELECT  nodeId 
FROM    cmsDataType 
WHERE   propertyEditorAlias = 'Umbraco.MultiNodeTreePicker'

DELETE FROM cmsDataTypePreValues
WHERE datatypeNodeId IN (SELECT id FROM @datatypeIds);

INSERT INTO cmsDataTypePreValues
SELECT
    [@datatypeIds].id,
    1,  
    1,
    'maxNumber'
FROM
@datatypeIds;

SELECT     *
FROM       cmsDataTypePreValues
WHERE     datatypeNodeId IN (SELECT id FROM @datatypeIds)
GO
```

But I'm not sure if it'll fix my issue? **I'm also not sure what the poster there means by**:

> Be aware that this will remove all prevalues for specified datatypes.
>   Application pool recycle will be needed afterwards.

Comment: This comment is not gonna help you.. but, one thing I learned over the years with Umbraco: NEVER upgrade your instance! If I were you, I would rollback to v6 and be happy with that version.

Comment: Unfortunately building on top of 6 is counter productive for long term maintainability and speed. If you have any ideas on how to fix the issue please feel free to weigh in though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update -- so I tried running the SQL script specified in that link that would fix the multinode treepicker. However, it didn't work for me and seemed to drop my members...which was bad. Fortunately backups exist and I got a backup version swapped into place.

I traced the issue down to a couple of data types that use the multinode treepicker though and don't load properly (these are specified as generic properties for the member type).

Update 2 (**Solution**): This was resolved by changing the properties in the member type from the broken datatypes (which I deleted) to a label / text string. Also the SQL didn't drop my members, deleting my member type and then recreating it to trace down the problem removed all members of that type.